# How to normalize a non-integrable function?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, integration, normalization

Given is $$ \Psi(x,t) = N \exp \left(-ax^2 + ibt \right) $$ 
On the particle acts a force which is:   $$ F = -kx$$ that means that the potential is: $$V = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$$ the Time-Dependent Schrödinger equation would then look like this: 
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Psi = \left[\frac{-\hbar^2}{2\mu}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2 } + \frac{1}{2}kx^2 \right]\Psi$$ where $\Psi$ is the one considered above.

Then $a$ and $b$ should come out to be $a = \frac{\mu}{2\hbar}, b = \frac{1}{2}$ .

The question is : how do I choose N such that $\Psi$ is normalized? 
Because when I compute $\Psi^*\Psi $ the imaginary part disappears but then I'm left with a negative exponent of second degree, which is of course not integrable. Should I use the second or third order Taylor approximation of the function?

Comment: The function $\exp(-ax^2)$ is integrable over the reals. The integral is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{a}}$.

Comment: @nicoguaro: perhaps you can write an answer based on your comment.

Comment: this may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: This expression is very common and the integral and variations on it are well known.  It is a type of [Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral of $e^{-A x^2}$ from $0$ to $\infty$ is well-known and [given by](http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/PChem/notes/Integral.pdf):

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} dx \space e^{-A x^2} = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{\pi}{A})^\frac{1}{2}
$$

Since $e^{-A x^2}$ is symmetric about $x = 0$ the integral from $-\infty$ to $0$ would be the same, so the total integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $(\frac{\pi}{A})^\frac{1}{2}$, where $A = \frac{\mu}{\hbar}$ (since $\psi $*$ \psi$ = $N^2 e^{-2 a x^2}$ for $a = \frac{\mu}{2\hbar}$). You can then use this to find $N$.

Comment: But what if for example I want to compute $\langle x \rangle $ ? is this integral still computable?

Comment: Sure, take a look at the link I included. It includes an integral that you would need for that. That's also neglecting the fact that the integral of $x e^{-ax^2}$ can be computed by hand easily.

Comment: How tho? I tried integrating by parts and I got $\frac{\pi\mu}{\hbar}$ but I $\langle x \rangle$ should be zero because it's odd right?

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYi8fmi7e7I) can explain how to do the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Your wave function is nicely quadratically integrable, i.e. $$\Psi \Psi_*=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  exp(-2ax^2)dx $$ is finite as you can find in any integral table for definite integrals.  That's the significance of "integrable' here. It does not mean that you have to find an indefinite integral analytically.